# Unable to connect to RDS from Elastic Beanstalk Docker

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

My spring boot app deployed in Elastic Beanstalks docker is unable to connect to external RDS. It always stuck at "com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Starting..." during app startup.

**Dockerfile**
(I added the db connection details in ENTRYPOINT for troubleshooting purpose)

```
    FROM openjdk:8
    WORKDIR "/mrbs"
    ARG JAR_FILE=target/*jar
    COPY ${JAR_FILE} ./app.jar
    EXPOSE 8080
    #CMD ["java","-jar","./app.jar"]
    ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","./app.jar","--spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://[security].[security].ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/mrbs?serverTimezone=GMT%2B8","--spring.datasource.password=[security]","--spring.datasource.username=[security]","--logging.file.path=/mrbs/logs/"]
```

**Dockerrun.aws.json**

```
    {
      "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
      "containerDefinitions": [
        {
          "name": "api",
          "image": "[security]/mrbs-backend",
          "hostname": "api",
          "essential": true,
          "memory": 128
        }
      ]
    }
```

**.travis.yml**

```
    language: generic
    sudo: required
    services:
      - docker
    before_install:
    install: skip
    before_script:
    script:
      - mvn -f mrbs-backend clean package
      - docker build -t [security]/mrbs-backend ./mrbs-backend
      - echo "$DOCKER_PASSWORD" |docker login -u "$DOKCER_ID" --password-stdin
      - docker push [security]/mrbs-backend
    
    deploy:
      skip_cleanup: true
      provider: elasticbeanstalk
      region: ap-southeast-1
      #app: mrbs-docker
      app: mrbs
      env: Mrbs-env-3
      bucket_name: elasticbeanstalk-ap-southeast-1-[security]351
      bucket_patch: mrbs
      on:
        branch: master
      access_key_id: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY
      secret_access_key: $AWS_SECRET_KEY
```

Added security group ***mrbs-intra-docker*** to both RDS and Elastic Beanstalk
RDS Security Group
[(image),](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYIUY.png)
Elastic Beanstalk Security Group
[(image),](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6z4j.png)
EC2 Security Group
[(image),](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xXZF.png)

When I check the log from elastic beanstalk, it shows that spring boot app stuck at "com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Starting..." during startup.

```
      .   ____          _            __ _ _
     /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
    ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
     \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
      '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
     =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
     :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.3.RELEASE)
    
    2020-11-01 09:14:16,590 [main] INFO   c.j.m.MeetingRoomBookingSystemApplication - Starting MeetingRoomBookingSystemApplication v1.0 on api with PID 1 (/mrbs/app.jar started by root in /mrbs)
    2020-11-01 09:14:16,599 [main] DEBUG  c.j.m.MeetingRoomBookingSystemApplication - Running with Spring Boot v2.3.3.RELEASE, Spring v5.2.8.RELEASE
    2020-11-01 09:14:16,600 [main] INFO   c.j.m.MeetingRoomBookingSystemApplication - The following profiles are active: dev
    2020-11-01 09:14:19,408 [main] INFO   o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFERRED mode.
    2020-11-01 09:14:19,729 [main] INFO   o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 294ms. Found 7 JPA repository interfaces.
    2020-11-01 09:14:21,469 [main] INFO   o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler@c03cf28' of type [org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
    2020-11-01 09:14:21,513 [main] INFO   o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' of type [org.springframework.security.access.method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
    2020-11-01 09:14:22,602 [main] INFO   o.s.b.w.e.tomcat.TomcatWebServer - Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
    2020-11-01 09:14:22,639 [main] INFO   o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol - Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
    2020-11-01 09:14:22,640 [main] INFO   o.a.catalina.core.StandardService - Starting service [Tomcat]
    2020-11-01 09:14:22,640 [main] INFO   o.a.catalina.core.StandardEngine - Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.37]
    2020-11-01 09:14:22,826 [main] INFO   o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
    2020-11-01 09:14:22,827 [main] INFO   o.s.b.w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 6052 ms
    2020-11-01 09:14:24,415 [main] INFO   o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor - Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
    2020-11-01 09:14:24,516 [main] INFO   com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Starting...
```

However, If I ***directly*** run the docker from EC2 command line, the spring boot can be started successfully, which means ec2 instance is able to connect to rds using the same image...

```
    [ec2-user@ip-172-31-24-202 ~]$ docker image ls
    REPOSITORY                TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
    [secruity]/mrbs-backend   latest              bd84014e90df        9 minutes ago       570MB
    amazon/amazon-ecs-agent   latest              ebac5fda27cb        8 weeks ago         67MB
    [ec2-user@ip-172-31-24-202 ~]$ docker run [secruity]/mrbs-backend
    
      .   ____          _            __ _ _
     /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
    ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
     \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
      '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
     =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
     :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.3.RELEASE)
    
    2020-11-01 09:36:39,075 [main] INFO   c.j.m.MeetingRoomBookingSystemApplication - Starting MeetingRoomBookingSystemApplication v1.0 on 1d93b8a14d12 with PID 1 (/mrbs/app.jar started by root in /mrbs)
    2020-11-01 09:36:39,087 [main] DEBUG  c.j.m.MeetingRoomBookingSystemApplication - Running with Spring Boot v2.3.3.RELEASE, Spring v5.2.8.RELEASE
    2020-11-01 09:36:39,088 [main] INFO   c.j.m.MeetingRoomBookingSystemApplication - The following profiles are active: dev
    2020-11-01 09:36:44,035 [main] INFO   o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFERRED mode.
    2020-11-01 09:36:44,558 [main] INFO   o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 474ms. Found 7 JPA repository interfaces.
    2020-11-01 09:36:47,066 [main] INFO   o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler@c03cf28' of type [org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
    2020-11-01 09:36:47,107 [main] INFO   o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' of type [org.springframework.security.access.method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
    2020-11-01 09:36:49,047 [main] INFO   o.s.b.w.e.tomcat.TomcatWebServer - Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
    2020-11-01 09:36:49,099 [main] INFO   o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol - Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
    2020-11-01 09:36:49,106 [main] INFO   o.a.catalina.core.StandardService - Starting service [Tomcat]
    2020-11-01 09:36:49,107 [main] INFO   o.a.catalina.core.StandardEngine - Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.37]
    2020-11-01 09:36:49,546 [main] INFO   o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
    2020-11-01 09:36:49,549 [main] INFO   o.s.b.w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 10161 ms
    2020-11-01 09:36:51,992 [main] INFO   o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor - Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
    2020-11-01 09:36:52,141 [main] INFO   com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Starting...
    2020-11-01 09:36:54,622 [main] INFO   com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
    filePath=/mrbs/logs/
    2020-11-01 09:36:55,296 [main] DEBUG  com.jiangwensi.mrbs.AppContext - setApplicationContext is called
    2020-11-01 09:36:55,528 [task-1] INFO   o.h.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
    2020-11-01 09:36:56,161 [main] WARN   o.s.b.a.o.j.JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration - spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
    2020-11-01 09:36:58,427 [task-1] INFO   org.hibernate.Version - HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.20.Final
    2020-11-01 09:36:58,874 [main] DEBUG  o.s.s.w.a.e.ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource - Adding web access control expression 'permitAll', for Ant [pattern='/auth/signUp', POST]
    2020-11-01 09:36:58,887 [main] DEBUG  o.s.s.w.a.e.ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource - Adding web access control expression 'permitAll', for Ant [pattern='/auth/verifyEmail', GET]
    2020-11-01 09:36:58,888 [main] DEBUG  o.s.s.w.a.e.ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource - Adding web access control expression 'permitAll', for Ant [pattern='/auth/requestResetForgottenPassword', POST]
    2020-11-01 09:36:58,888 [main] DEBUG  o.s.s.w.a.e.ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource - Adding web access control expression 'permitAll', for Ant [pattern='/auth/resetForgottenPassword', POST]
    2020-11-01 09:36:58,889 [main] DEBUG  o.s.s.w.a.e.ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource - Adding web access control expression 'permitAll', for Ant [pattern='/auth/resetPassword', POST]
    2020-11-01 09:36:58,892 [main] DEBUG  o.s.s.w.a.e.ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource - Adding web access control expression 'authenticated', for any request
    2020-11-01 09:36:59,011 [main] DEBUG  o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Validated configuration attributes
    2020-11-01 09:36:59,020 [main] DEBUG  o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Validated configuration attributes
    2020-11-01 09:36:59,036 [main] INFO   o.s.s.w.DefaultSecurityFilterChain - Creating filter chain: any request, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@31bcf236, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@4c51cf28, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@289710d9, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@4b3ed2f0, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@3549bca9, com.jiangwensi.mrbs.security.LoginAuthenticationFilter@4fad9bb2, com.jiangwensi.mrbs.security.JwtAuthenticationFilter@517d4a0d, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@5143c662, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@71c27ee8, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@7862f56, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@3da30852, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@4eb386df, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@134d26af]
    2020-11-01 09:36:59,324 [main] DEBUG  o.s.s.a.i.a.MethodSecurityInterceptor - Validated configuration attributes
    2020-11-01 09:36:59,643 [main] INFO   o.h.validator.internal.util.Version - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.1.5.Final
    2020-11-01 09:37:01,174 [task-1] INFO   o.h.annotations.common.Version - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
    2020-11-01 09:37:03,566 [task-1] INFO   org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
    2020-11-01 09:37:05,670 [main] DEBUG  o.s.s.c.a.a.c.AuthenticationConfiguration$EnableGlobalAuthenticationAutowiredConfigurer - Eagerly initializing {webSecurityConfigurator=com.jiangwensi.mrbs.security.WebSecurityConfigurator$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$aa3555ad@1a20270e}
    2020-11-01 09:37:05,692 [main] INFO   o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol - Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
    2020-11-01 09:37:06,111 [main] INFO   o.s.b.w.e.tomcat.TomcatWebServer - Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
    2020-11-01 09:37:06,136 [main] INFO   o.s.d.r.c.DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener - Triggering deferred initialization of Spring Data repositories…
    2020-11-01 09:37:09,726 [task-1] INFO   o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator - HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
    2020-11-01 09:37:09,802 [task-1] INFO   o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
    2020-11-01 09:37:12,036 [main] INFO   o.s.d.r.c.DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener - Spring Data repositories initialized!
    2020-11-01 09:37:12,065 [main] INFO   c.j.m.MeetingRoomBookingSystemApplication - Started MeetingRoomBookingSystemApplication in 36.293 seconds (JVM running for 42.707)
    2020-11-01 09:37:12,073 [main] DEBUG  c.j.mrbs.InitializeApplicationData - onApplicationEvent is called
```

Comment: You are using multi-cointainer EB, which means your container runs on ECS. Have you checked ECS console? Maybe it has extra info, especially in ECS->Service->Events?

Comment: I checked ECS and it says the container is STOPPED (OutOfMemoryError: Container killed due to memory u). So I increased the memory in Dockerrun.aws.json and the issue is resolved. Thanks for the advise!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused by **not sufficient memory** allocated to the container.

The **solution** was to increase the memory.